# Execute INTO to accept NULL values

Tags: postgresql, insert, plpgsql, execute

I have searched the internet and cannot find any information or examples of how to use EXECUTE INTO including when the stamement may return nothing.

I am getting the error

query string argument of EXECUTE is null

I have tried using IF EXISTS() 
Creating a statement that includes a count and a whole raft of things.At this point I feel like im going around in circles. FRUSTRATING!

Is there a default method for doing this?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the **real** code of your PL/pgSQL function. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `execute format('select 1 where false') into t` will put nothing to t, so later `execute t` would give

> ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null

so simple coalesce will help:

```
t=# do $$
declare t text;
begin
execute format('select 1 where %L',false) into t;
execute coalesce(t,'select now()') into t;
raise '%',t;
end;
$$
;
ERROR:  2017-07-11 16:11:03.149521+00
Time: 0.349 ms
```